# Get next_post_link which is Sticky?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the link of next Sticky post with it's title using:

```
<h2><?php next_post_link('%link') ?></h2>
```

I have tried passing `TRUE` argument but that only filters the taxonomy not Sticky Posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option in next_post_link to just get sticky post (correct me if i am wrong) . You need custom navigation here. First you need to get all sticky post in array and then make next posts links :

```
// get all sticky posts
$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');
// if there are any
if (!empty($sticky)) {
    // newest IDs first, optional
    rsort($sticky);
    $args = array(
        'post__in' => $sticky
    );
    $postlist = get_posts();
    $posts = array();
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $posts[] = get_the_ID();
    }

    //wp_reset_postdata(); uncomment this, if this is a nested loop
$current = array_search($post->ID, $posts);
$prevID = $posts[$current-1];
$nextID = $posts[$current+1];

// Link for previous post
if (!empty($prevID)) {
    echo '<div><a href="'. get_permalink($prevID) .'">Prev</a></div>';
}

// Link for next post
if (!empty($nextID)) {
    echo '<div><a href="'. get_permalink($nextID) .'">Next</a></div>';
}
 }
```

Comment: There seems to be an error in while loop. :( 
one bug is use of + operator but still there is some error.

Comment: No you don't have to use  +  or . I have update the answer check now.

Comment: That was super genius! Thanks.

Comment: $postlist = get_posts();  isn't necessary